Prove $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}\right)$ is convex
Prove that $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}\right)$, $x\in (0,1)$ is convex for $a\geq 5$.
I've tried with the classical characterization of convex functions:
$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \leq \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$$
Since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, it can be shown that proving the earlier inequality for $\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ actually proves $f(x)$'s convexity (I take this step just for convenience). I'm currently stucked at proving that
$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^a}{1-\frac{x+y}{2}}\leq\left(\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-y^a}{1-y}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$
I've also tried the alternative way of showing that $f''(x)\geq 0$, which leaves me hopelessly trying to show that
$$(p''q)pq - \left((p'q)^2-(pq')^2\right)\geq 0$$
for $p(x):=1-x^a$ and $q(x):=1-x$
I thought considering just the integral case for a, $a\in\mathbb{N}$ would make things easier, as this leads to
$$
f(x) = log\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{a-1}\right)
$$
Naming $s(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} x^i$, proving $f''(x)\geq 0$ then amounts to showing that
$$s''(x)s(x)-\left(s'(x)\right)^2\geq 0$$
Which I don't know how to approach either.
Any help is kindly appreciated.

It's a finite geometric series, and every term has non-negative second derivative. Doesn't that pretty much prove it?

Hey, thank you for your answer; I did forget to write the log at the beginning of the function... my bad. Already edited it.

Hi, no problem! With a log I am not sure how to prove it. Sketching seems to indicate $a=2$ is the only case where it is not convex, but I can only tell by looking. I tried doing the derivative, but it's a lot of algebra and I'm not sure how to solve the resulting equation.

By doing the derivative, we end up with an equation $p(x)\geq 0$, with $deg(p)=2a$. So the problem turns into proving that a polynomial of degree $2a$ has no roots in $(0,1)$. By the way, by graphing $f(x)$ you can see that it is convex only for $a \geq 5$, as asked in the proof.
